# Localization in .NET Core 2 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, .net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I've followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization) for getting my localization to work with my validation. But either I've done something wrong, or it isn't supported.

I have a `Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Customer value)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Ok("Good job!");
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

I register my localizations like so:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

And my model:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my resx and my directory (all resx look alike):

[image]

[image]

What I want is to let the resource-file determine what message is passed for the propertyname when it's invalid.

Making this POST:

```
{
    "firstname":"John"
}
```

Will currently return:

```
{
    "LastName": [
        "The LastName field is required."
    ]
}
```

**Since I created a `Resource` for the `Customer` model I want the result to return this:**

```
{
    "LastName": [
        "The Surname field is required."
    ]
}
```

I know I can use `Display` like this:

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Models_Customer), Name = "FirstName")]
```

...but I thought that the entire point of [naming the resource-files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#resource-file-naming) based on the model was to avoid it.

Comment: A simpler way is to use [DisplayName("FirstName")]. However I was not able to do the localization directly based on property name.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. But I guess, it works only with resx filnames like this:

Models.Customer.**en-GB**.resx

I tried it like you but this file name works only with culture region information.

Greeds

P.S.: I'm open for a solution like Models.Customer.**en**.resx

Comment: may be this is a solution? I don't know: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1